# Error: The Android SDK could not be found, please set the path to it in the Xamarin.Android SDKs settings panel. (TestAndroid)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

Error: The Android SDK could not be found, please set the path to it in the Xamarin.Android SDKs settings panel. (TestAndroid)

[image: Error image:]

I have selected android-sdk folder but it not works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the Android SDK from the [official website](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads).
Then open the SDK manager and download the necessary addins. After that select the SDK location in the preferences of Xamarin. Make sure you have enough rights to read the folder.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. In previous sdk adb.exe was not downloded but now it is downloaded. So, Now it works.

Comment: Hi, i'm a beginner on android programming, and i stuck on this problem too.. i have download the  command line tools and i do not know what addins needs to install. any advice?

Answer (score 2):

For MAC system,

Download Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

open **android-sdk-macosx > tools**

right click on **android** open with terminal to open SDK manager, install required plug-ins and you are good to go