# Provide AndroidSDK path to mdtool on mac

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.android, mdtool

I am building Xamarin.Adnroid project with an mdtool from rakefile as a step in TeamCity build configuration.

The call is:

```
/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool build "--configuration:Debug" -p:"Project.Droid" -t:Build "Project.sln"
```

This (and even if I set -p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/Users/user/AndroidSDK) gives an error:

> error: The Android SDK could not be found, please set the path to it
>   in the Xamarin.Android SDKs settings panel.

I can use xbuild to build the project and specify the AndroidSDKPath via:

```
/usr/local/bin/xbuild Droid/Project.Droid.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:AndroidSdkDirectory=/Users/user/AndroidSDK
```

but sine my solution hots both, Android and iOS projects, I'd like to be able to build both with mdtool.

Note that this question is unrelated to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737608/error-the-android-sdk-could-not-be-found-please-set-the-path-to-it-in-the-xama) since the later of deals with the UI builds which work great in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to open Xamarin Studio on the build host and configure the SDK path under Preferences > SDK Locations > Android. That should fix your problem.